# How can I store the value entered in a parameter query in a declared variable?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I would like to store the value a user enters in a parameter query to a declared variable; how can i do this?

For example:

```
Dim storeHere as Integer

// other vba statements

stmnt = //other sql statements

        "WHERE [Student].[Class] = [Enter Class:] " & _

        // other sql statements
```

So i would like to store the value the user enters as class in the variable `storeHere`.
How can i achieve this. Please help.
 NB: I am using access

Comment: How is the user entering the value? By a pop-up or cell?

Comment: Through a meesage box that appears by default (in access).

Comment: Ok so how is that value being assigned to the `storeHere` integer?

Comment: `stmnt = "WHERE [Student].[Class] = [Enter Class:] " & storeHere` should do?

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a saved query in Access named [getStudentsByClass]

```sql
PARAMETERS [Enter Class:] Short;
SELECT Student.*
FROM Student
WHERE (((Student.Class)=[Enter Class:]));
```

If you run it interactively it will prompt "Enter Class:" and then display the corresponding results. If you want to run that query from VBA code you need to prompt for the parameter value first, then run the query via a QueryDef object

```vbs
Dim storeHere As Integer
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset

storeHere = InputBox("Enter class:", "Enter Parameter Value")
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("getStudentsByClass")
qdf![Enter Class:] = storeHere
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

' Do what you want with the returned records. For demo purposes:
Debug.Print rst.RecordCount & " record(s) returned."

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```